# Approximating a real number by a fraction from one side

Tags: number-theory, inequality, diophantine-approximation

[Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) tells us that for any real number $\alpha$, we have a sequence of rational approximations of $\alpha$ that are good for how big their denominator is. More precisely: given an integer $N \ge 1$, there exists a rational number $\frac pq$ with $1 \le q \le N$ such that $$\left|\alpha - \frac pq\right| < \frac1{qN}.$$

(This error is less than $\frac1{q^2}$, and [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) tells us that for algebraic numbers, the exponent here is best possible.)

The absolute values tell us that the fraction $\frac pq$ is either going to be slightly smaller or slightly larger than $\alpha$. What if I want to specify which one it is? For example, suppose I want to find $\frac pq$ such that $$\frac pq < \alpha < \frac pq + \epsilon.$$ How small can I make $\epsilon$ (related to $q$, or possibly some extra parameter $N$ as above)?

I'm a bit worried when it comes to numbers such as Liouville's constant $L = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}$, which has *extremely* good approximations (by truncating the series), but all from below; similarly, $1-L$ will have extremely good approximations, but all from above.

Comment: If "large" entries occur in the simple continued fraction expansion only at even or only at odd positions, we do not have "very good" approximations from both sides.

Comment: But you can get arbitary close to the number from both sides, if you do not care how good this approximation is compared to the magnitude of the denominator.

Comment: Both good points, but I'd like to quantify how good the approximations we can get are. So, for example, the naive approach of saying $\alpha \approx \frac{\lfloor q\alpha \rfloor}{q}$ tells us that we can always get approximations with error at most $\frac1q$.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see how the bound rules out the possibility that there's infinitely many fractions above $\alpha$ with error $O(\frac1{q^2})$, but none or only few below $\alpha$.

Comment: A good point which I did not think about! But if you are confident with an error less than $\frac{1}{q^2}$, then every convergent does the job. So, this bound can definitely be achieved from both sides. Intuitively, I would say that the Hurwitz-bound can be achieved from both sides infinite many often, but I admit that I cannot prove it.

Comment: Say $p>q$, and $gcd(p,q)=1$ (we can't guarantee this) and  $p/q<\alpha$. Now write $qr-ps=1$ with $r,s$ small  Then $\dfrac{r}{s}-\dfrac{p}{q}=\dfrac{1}{qs}$ and $r/s$ might work as an upper bound with a small error.

Comment: Another idea is to first approximate with a very large denominator (in terms of the original N) and then scale it down either side.

Comment: @Aravind The continued-fraction-method actually finds such fractions squeezing $\alpha$ and the construction guarantees $gcd(p,q)=1$. So, an error less than $\frac{1}{q^2}$ from either side can always be achieved for every irrational number. Moreover, infinite many such fractions for either side exist because the fractions are alternatingly below and above $\alpha$.

Comment: @Peter, yes continued fraction convergents alternate on either side. I was just trying to get one approximation from another. Does the Hurwitz theorem also come from continued fractions?

Comment: @Aravind Yes, it does. From $3$ consecutive convegrnts, at least one has an error less than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}$. If we only have two consecutive convergents, at least one has an error less than $\frac{1}{2q^2}$, but this does not necessarily imply that we have such approximations from below AND above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the answers in the comments:

A more quantitative version of Dirichlet's approximation theorem is Hurwitz's theorem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory))), which guarantees the existence of infinitely many approximations $\frac pq$ such that $$\left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac1{\sqrt 5\,q^2},$$ which is tight: for some $\alpha$, no better approximation exists. Moreover, these approximations can be found from truncating the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$.

This, by itself, does not guarantee us which side the approximation is on. However, the continued fraction convergents $\frac{h_n}{k_n}$ satisfy $$\frac{h_{2n}}{k_{2n}} < \alpha < \frac{h_{2n+1}}{k_{2n+1}}$$ and also $$\left|\alpha - \frac{h_n}{k_n}\right| < \frac1{k_n k_{n+1}}.$$ (See, e.g., [this link](http://www.math.jacobs-university.de/timorin/PM/continued_fractions.pdf).) So the even convergents give us a close approximation from below: $$\frac{h_{2n}}{k_{2n}} < \alpha < \frac{h_{2n}}{k_{2n}} + \frac1{k_{2n}^2}.$$ Similarly, the odd convergents give us a close approximation from above.

Asymptotically, this is the best error we can hope for. We could hope to improve the constant on $\frac{1}{q^2}$ to make it closer to Hurwitz's theorem. However, experimentally, it seems like the constant of $1$ is actually best possible. If I take $\alpha$ to be the infinite continued fraction $$\alpha = 1 + \frac{1}{100 + \frac1{1 + \frac1{100 + \frac1{\ddots}}}} = \frac{5 + \sqrt{26}}{10}$$ then the continued fraction convergents give errors of $\approx \frac{0.98}{q^2}$ from one side and $\approx \frac{0.0098}{q^2}$ from the other: we pay for good approximations from below with bad approximations from above.

This is not a proof, because I haven't said anything about the quality of other, non-continued-fraction approximations to $\frac{5 + \sqrt{26}}{10}$. But it's very suggestive of what the answer might be, isn't it?